# SSRS BIDS Expression to pick visibility based on AD GROUPS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have a box with the text 'Dill Down Facility Available' (see screenshot)

When the report is run I only want certain people to see this box.

The people I want to see this box are contained in 19 different ADGROUPS

There will be others who run this, but I need them to see everything bar the yellow box.

If I right click the box and go to:
TextBoxProperties > Visibility > Show or hide based on an expression,

I am able to enter an expression.

The one ive written in the screenshot allows me to pick 1 individuals AD name in the following format:

```
DOMAINNAME\ADNAME
```

However, if I put an ADGROUP name instead of the ADNAME, it does not work, and instead everyone can see the yellow box.

As the expression contains

```
User!UserID
```

I believe this may be stopping my ADGROUP name working as its looking for a USER, although this would not explain why it then allows anyone to see this box.

Can anyone provide the expression to allow either:

a) 1 group name
b) multiple group names

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSRS does not have this functionality built in, you'll need to use a Custom Assembly and reference it in your project.

See: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/920769